# modx 2.2.0-pl2 problems after clean install

Tags: installation, modx

I'm using modx-2.2.0-pl2 (revo).

Did a clean install without any error, but after login in into backend I only see the dashboard. After clicking any option i get only the menu with a blank screen under it.

Dont get any errors. Any suggestions or ideas?

**Edit**: after many f5 the separate categories will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to remember exactly why this happens, but am drawing a blank.... but you can fix it by disabling javascript & css caching for the manager pages [not for the front end] - I believe it is under the system & server settings. If you can't get into that [after repeated F5s] - you can go int the database system settings table and toggle both settings to '0'

Comment: did u mean javascript & css compress?

Comment: CSS & js compression - sorry, yes that's what I meant.